# mousewheel.jsの横スクロールについて質問です

Tags: javascript, jquery

横スクロールのwebサイトを制作していて、スクロール処理を
http://www.webopixel.net/javascript/421.html
上記のサイトを参考（コードはコピペ）して制作したのですが、

speedを50にするとマウスホイールではちょうどいいスクロール量でスクロールされるのですが、トラックパッド(macbook)の場合スクロール量が大きすぎて、暴れ馬のようになっていしまいます。。

上記サイトのデモではマウスのスクロールでもトラックパッドのスクロールでもスクロール量が適切なのですが、自分で作るとスクロール量の違いが出てしまいます。

スクロール方法をマウスかトラックパッドか判定方法などがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

リンク先のページのものを試してみました。
内部で利用されている `jquery.mousewheel.min.js` に原因があるようです。
最初に現時点での最新版の [v3.1.13](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js) で試しましたが、トラックパッドでは確かに暴れ馬でした。
次にリンク先のページで使われているものに近いバージョンの [v3.0.6](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js) で試したところ、リンク先のものと同等の動きになりました。

こちらを試してみはどうでしょう。